# Merge two objects in javascript having an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, concatenation

I have two objects a and b. Each has an array results [] which further contains multiple objects.

I want to merge the results [] array from both the objects into third object c.

I have tried `var c = Object.assign(a,b)` but I am not getting the result.

Consider following example for reference.

`a = {results[{"boys": 50, "girls": 20, "red":10},{boys": 40, "girls": 10, "red":50},{boys": 30, "girls": 10, "red":50}]}`

`b = {results[{boys": 20, "girls": 30},{boys": 50, "girls": 20},{boys": 70, "girls": 30}]}`

I am looking for result as follows

`c = {results[{"boys": 50, "girls": 20, "red":10},{boys": 40, "girls": 10, "red":50},{boys": 30, "girls": 10, "red":50},{boys": 20, "girls": 30},{boys": 50, "girls": 20},{boys": 70, "girls": 30}]}`

Please help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Excuse me but https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+merge+two+arrays.

Comment: You are missing the opening quotes for the "boys" key and _"results["_ is invalid...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to worry about, before merging two arrays, is making sure that your syntax is correct.

1. Your JavaScript objects are incorrect. You need a colon (`:`) following your `"results"` key.
2. You are missing opening quotes for your `"boys"` keys.

Once you have fixed these issues, merging is as simple as using the spread syntax to create a new `"results"` array within your `c` object.

Unfortunately deep-merging does not exist in ES6, so the following will not work:

```js
const c = { ...a, ...b }
```

Instead, you will need to merge your objects' `"results"`.

```js
const a = {
  "results": [
    { "boys": 50, "girls": 20, "red": 10 },
    { "boys": 40, "girls": 10, "red": 50 },
    { "boys": 30, "girls": 10, "red": 50 }
  ]
}

const b = {
  "results": [
    { "boys": 20, "girls": 30 },
    { "boys": 50, "girls": 20 },
    { "boys": 70, "girls": 30 }
  ]
}

const c = { "results": [ ...a.results, ...b.results ] }

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```